# Ajax post method works with problem, in asp.net core project

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a code in asp.net core, that it reads all rows from "Color" table of database (in SQL server) and Shows this data in a data table. Above this table, There is a button after clicking, an accordion opens and shows a form that can insert a new row to below table.

I have a controller called "ColorController" that has 3 actions: ShowColors, Insert(get mode), Insert(post mode).

**ColorController.cs** :

```
    private IColor _icolor;

    public ColorController(IColor icolor)
    {
        _icolor = icolor;
    }

    public IActionResult ShowColors()
    {
        return View(_icolor.ShowColors());
    }

    public IActionResult Insert()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(ColorViewModel colorViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_icolor.isColorExist(colorViewModel.ColorCode))
            {
                ViewBag.Validation = 1;
                ModelState.AddModelError("ColorCode", "Exist!");
                return View(colorViewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Validation = 0;    
                
                // ... Insert codes

                return RedirectToAction("ShowColors","Color");                   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Validation = 1;
            return View(colorViewModel);
        }
    }
```

I write 2 views for actions of color controller. These views:

**ShowColors.cshtml:**

```
@model IEnumerable<DataAccessLayer.Entities.Color>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-row">
                <a class="accordion-header" href="#">
                    <button type="button" onclick='Insert() >
                        InsertColor
                    </button>
                </a>
                <div class="accordion-body" id="InsertForm">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
            <table id="example" class="table table-hover">

              @*...Show datatable...*@

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
   function Insert() {
       var _url = '@Url.Action("Insert", "Color")';
        $.ajax({
           url: _url,
           type: "Get",
           data: {}
        }).done(function (result) {
           $('#InsertForm').html(result);
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Insert.cshtml** (I use "IsValid" Input for check validation.)

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form>
            <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Validation" id="validation" />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ColorCode" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="ColorCode" class="form-control" id="txtColorCode" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="ColorCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ColorName" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="ColorName" class="form-control" id="txtColorName" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="ColorName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="ml-3 mt-3">
                        <button type="submit" onclick='InsertColor()' >Add Color</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function InsertColor() {
        var _url = '@Url.Action("Insert", "Color")';
        $.ajax({
            url: _url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                ColorCode: $("#txtColorCode").val(),
                ColorName: $("#txtColorName").val(),
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#InsertForm').html(response);
                var isValid = $('body').find('[name="IsValid"]').val();
                if (isValid == 1) {
                    stop();
                }
            },
            complete: function (xhr, status) {
                var isValid = $('body').find('[name="IsValid"]').val();
                console.log("Is valid =" + isValid);
                if (isValid != 1)
                {
                    if (status == 'success')
                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ShowColors", "Color")';
                }
            },
        }).done(function (result) {
            $('#InsertForm').html(result);
                var isValid = $('body').find('[name="IsValid"]').val();
                if (isValid != 1) {
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ShowColors", "Color")';
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

When I run code, everything is OK until I want to insert a new color. GET mode (Insert action) works true, but POST mode have problems. In First time that I add a new color and model State is not valid, the code doesn't work. In next times, If model state is valid, New row insert in database but in table of "ShowColors" view doesn't see. I reload showColors action in code, but in address bar, address has parameters, like this:

> localhost:.../Color/ShowColors?IsValid=&ColorCode=pur&ColorName=purple

While I want to show this:

> localhost:.../Color/ShowColors

I guess ajax function in "Insert" view is wrong, but I can't find bug. Can someone help me, where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run code, everything is OK until I want to insert a new color.
> GET mode (Insert action) works true, but POST mode have problems. In
> First time that I add a new color and model State is not valid, the
> code doesn't work. In next times, If model state is valid, New row
> insert in database but in table of "ShowColors" view doesn't see. I
> reload showColors action in code, but in address bar, address has
> parameters,

Please check the code in the `Insert.cshtml`, I have checked it on my sample, it seems that it will trigger the default submit action via the submit button and the JavaScript script not working. If I move the JavaScript script in the ShowColors page, the JavaScript script working, but since you are using `done()` and `complete()` method, after the ajax success function, it will trigger this function and refresh the main page.

After inserting the new color success via Ajax, in the Ajax success function, we could use  JQuery to add the new color to the color list, or use Ajax method to call the action method then update the color table content.

You could refer the following sample code: user partial view to display the Color list and Insert New Color.

Model:

```
public class Color
{
    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public string ColorCode { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
}
public class ColorViewModel
{
    public string ColorCode { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
}
```

PVInsert.cshtml: use to insert new color

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.ColorViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Insert";
    Layout = "";
}
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form asp-action="Insert">
            <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Validation" id="validation" />

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ColorCode" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="ColorCode" class="form-control" id="txtColorCode" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="ColorCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ColorName" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="ColorName" class="form-control" id="txtColorName" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="ColorName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="ml-3 mt-3">
                    <button type="button" id="btnaddcolor">Add Color</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

_PVShowAllColor.cshtml: use to display the color list.

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Color>
<table id="example" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ColorID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ColorCode)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ColorName)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ColorID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ColorCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ColorName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

ShowColors.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Color>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ShowColors";
}


<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-row">
                <a class="accordion-header" href="#">
                    <button type="button" onclick='Insert()'>
                        InsertColor
                    </button>
                </a>
                <div class="accordion-body" id="InsertForm">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div id="colorlist"> 
            <partial name="_PVShowAllColor" model="@Model" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<script>
    function Insert() {
        event.preventDefault();
       var _url = '@Url.Action("Insert", "Color")';
        $.ajax({
           url: _url,
           type: "Get",
           data: {}
        }).done(function (result) {
            $('#InsertForm').html(result);
            Addcolor();
        });
    }

    function Addcolor() {
          //find the add color button in the InsertForm, and then insert the new color.
            $("#btnaddcolor").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                var _url = '@Url.Action("Insert", "Color")';
                $.ajax({
                    url: _url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        ColorCode: $("#txtColorCode").val(),
                        ColorName: $("#txtColorName").val(),
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        //update the Insert Form.
                        $('#InsertForm').html(response);
                        //attach the click event for the AddColor button.
                        Addcolor();
                        var isValid = $('body').find('[name="IsValid"]').val();
                        if (isValid == 1) {
                            stop();
                        }
                        //after insert the new color success, call the ShowAllColor action method to update the partial view (display the latest data)
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("ShowAllColor", "Color")',
                            type: "Get",
                            success: function (responsedata) {
                                $('#colorlist').html(responsedata);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                });
            });
    }
</script>
```

ColorController:

```
public class ColorController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public ColorController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult ShowColors()
    {  
        return View(_context.Colors.ToList());
    }

    public IActionResult ShowAllColor()
    {
        return PartialView("_PVShowAllColor",_context.Colors.ToList());
    }

    public IActionResult Insert()
    {
        var newcolor = new ColorViewModel();
        return PartialView("_PVInsert", newcolor);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(ColorViewModel colorViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_context.Colors.Any(c => c.ColorCode == colorViewModel.ColorCode))
            {
                ViewBag.Validation = 1;
                ModelState.AddModelError("ColorCode", "Exist!");
                return PartialView("_PVInsert", colorViewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Validation = 0;

                var newcolor = new Color() { ColorCode = colorViewModel.ColorCode, ColorName = colorViewModel.ColorName };
                _context.Colors.Add(newcolor);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                var newcolorvm = new ColorViewModel();
                return PartialView("_PVInsert", newcolorvm);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Validation = 1;
            return PartialView("_PVInsert", colorViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot... My mistake was type of "AddColor" button! It has to be "button", not "submit"! I forgot completely and thought the problem is in ajax code... Thanks again n again.